# urllib3: How to get response when MaxRetryError is thrown?

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib3

I'm using the Retry module from Python `urllib3` + `requests` for a case where a 3rd party API gives sporadic errors. One issue I have is that if the retries keep failing, I get a `exceptions.MaxRetryError` and never get to see what the response was. What if there was valuable debugging data coming from the server?

Is there a way to still get the response in cases that would throw `MaxRetryError`?

Here's my code below

```
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter

def req_with_retry(retries=3, backoff_factor=0.5, status_forcelist=(400, 404, 500, 502, 504,), method_whitelist=frozenset(['POST', 'HEAD', 'TRACE', 'GET', 'PUT', 'OPTIONS', 'DELETE']), session=None,):
    ''' 
    this returns a session that functions like the requests module but with retries built it for certain status codes
    '''
    session = session or requests.Session()
    retry = Retry(
        total=retries,
        read=retries,
        connect=retries,
        backoff_factor=backoff_factor,
        status_forcelist=status_forcelist,
        method_whitelist=method_whitelist
    )
    adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
    session.mount('http://', adapter)
    session.mount('https://', adapter)
    return session

r = req_with_retry().get(url="https://www.google.com")
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, I would like to mention that `from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry` is no longer needed since urllib3 has been unvendored from requests. Consider using the `from urllib3.util.retry import Retry` form instead as it does not involve hacks (see https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/v2.22.0/requests/packages.py).

You can't get *both* the `MaxRetryError` and the response from urllib3. But you can get the response from urllib3, and use `raise_for_status` at the requests level. However, `raise_for_status()` won't be affected by your `status_forcelist`, so you may want to reimplement it yourself.

Here's an adaption of your code that 1/ retries on statuses 2/ prints the final response 3/ raises an exception.

```py
import logging

import urllib3
import requests
import requests.adapters

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger("urllib3").setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


def req_with_retry(
    retries=3,
    backoff_factor=0.5,
    status_forcelist=(400, 404, 500, 502, 504),
    method_whitelist=frozenset(
        ["POST", "HEAD", "TRACE", "GET", "PUT", "OPTIONS", "DELETE"]
    ),
    session=None,
):
    """Returns a session that functions like the requests module but with retries
    built it for certain status codes
    """
    session = session or requests.Session()
    retry = urllib3.Retry(
        total=retries,
        read=retries,
        connect=retries,
        backoff_factor=backoff_factor,
        status_forcelist=status_forcelist,
        method_whitelist=method_whitelist,
        raise_on_status=False,
    )
    adapter = requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
    session.mount("http://", adapter)
    session.mount("https://", adapter)
    return session


r = req_with_retry().get(url="https://httpbin.org/status/404")
print(r.status_code, r.text)
r.raise_for_status()
```

Comment: This question is about retries because if I didn't need retries I would just use `requests` and not touch `urllib3`. If a request fails with `requests` (400 err or 500 err or wtv) you can see the response. I'd be surprise if urllib3 doesn't let you but that's beside the point. In the end I need to a way to be able to Retry without losing the response data (only the last response, actually) in case those retries keep failing

Comment: There are many reasons to retry a request beside bad error codes, this is why I was confused. Thanks for clarifying. What you're asking makes more sense to me now, but it's still not possible without changing the code of urllib3. And it's not possible with requests either as request relies on urllib3 for retries. What is the behavior you would like to have? Having the response in the exception? Not raising an exception? Logging the response?

Comment: Oh wait no I understand what you want: you want to see the final response. You can achieve this with "raise_on_status=False", I'll update my answer.

Comment: The suggested edit queue is full, or I don't have permissions. Can someone verify that "However, raise_for_status() won't be affected by your status_forcelist, so you may want to reimplement it yourself." is still true because I'm not seeing how this aligns with whatever edit Quentin made.